# Create new span tags into others span

Tags: html

I have a code like this,

```
<div>
   <b>Hello</b>
   <span id=x class=highlight_red>
       how are
       <span id=y class=highlight_blue> you John?</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Now for example, with jquery or javascript, i want to set a new span tag on the text "are you" (http://jsfiddle.net/kgw57v3e/)

```
<div>
   <b>Hello</b>
   <span id=x class=highlight_red>
       how 
       <span id=z class=highlight_yellow>are
       <span id=y class=highlight_blue> you</span> John?</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

The problem is the span #z will close after the string "John?" and not after "you". 
Is there a way to resolve this kind of problem in javascript or jquery? (this is an example, if it is possible to have a solution that work dinamically with others contexts).

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what's happening here. This is expected specificity behavior--the CSS applied to the inner element takes precedence. The spans do not close where the color changes. Use your browser's document inspector to see this.

Comment: Spans cannot overlap each other like that. They can only be nested inside one another. So to simulate this behaviour, you would have to add a span 'z' around 'are' and a separate one around 'you', inside span 'y'. You can do this using JavaScript of course, but it won't be trivial and I don't know of any out of the box solution for it. And obviously, you cannot have to elements with the same id ('z'), but that's a minor implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol , i like your solution and yes, it's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#y').after("<span id='z'>bla bla</span>");
```